# Is necessary to create an explicit relation in the data base after defining it in the Sails js' model?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sails.js

I created a model with their respective relation using the following approach

> http://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/associations

and everything seems to be OK. But, when i open the model's tables which `SailsJs` created, in `Mysql` workbench. There isn't any relation between tables. So; do i need to specify the relations or leave the tables as they are and continue working with the relations that exists on `SailsJs`?

Comment: Share your model so it's clearer. Also, have already created data?

Answer (score 1):

Join table is required only for n-n relationships, not for 1-n ones.

Also, in `config/models.js`, if migrate is set to `'drop'` sails drops and creates all tables. When using `'alter'` it tries to create added tables, using `'safe'` it doesn't create added tables.

> There isn't any relation between tables

What type of relation are you expecting?

Comment: I'm starting working with sails. I normally work with cakephp, and to manage relations in cake, fisrt I have to do the relations in mysql, then, in the cake, i can use variables like belognsTo, hasOne, hasMany. In Sails seems like i dont have to do the same things

Comment: You can either create tables by writing SQL or use `alter` (experimental) / `drop` [settings](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/model-settings#?how-automigrations-work), if they fit your use case. In place of `belognsTo, hasOne, hasMany`, Sails has associations.